# Can I purchase songs from previous games without owning the original game?

Tags: rock-band-4

In Rock Band 4, I want to buy "Subdivisions" by Rush from Rock Band 3. I do not own Rock Band 3 but I still want the song. Can I purchase it for use in Rock Band 4 somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, songs from Rock Band 3 such as Subdivisions are available for Rock Band 4 through Legacy DLC.

You haven't provided a platform (Xbox, Playstation, etc.), but [this guide](http://forums.harmonixmusic.com/discussion/260620/rock-band-4-legacy-dlc-guide-updated-9-30-16) from Harmonix will walk you through how to obtain previously purchased or downloaded content.  In a nutshell, you basically export the content from Rock Band 3 and re-import it into Rock Band 4.

A full list of Rock Band 3 DLC songs compatible with Rock Band 4 can be found [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/rock-band-4/List_of_DLC_Songs).